# How to detect upload bandwidth to Flash media server

Tags: flash, upload, bandwidth, detect

I am trying to get the "bwcheck" application to work on FMS 4 on Amazon EC2, in order to detect my upload speed to the server and provide the best quality stream for my upload speed.

The tutorial I follow is this:

http://www.derekentringer.com/blog/flash-media-server-streaming-speed- testing-part-2-detect-upload-download-and-latency-speeds-and-port-conn ection/

or

http://web.archive.org/web/20080308081519/http://www.peldi.com/blog/ar chives/2004/01/automatically_c.html

Both are almost identical. However when I compile the .fla to .swf (having changed the URL for my server and application), and after I load the server-side code, I get the following error in my server-side log:

Method not found (recData)

I understand that apparently it is not finding the method, but I tried getting it off the function in the global scope, tried attaching it to the client, etc. but nothing worked. The original code of the server-side script is:

for ( i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
     data += "S->C";
}

Client.prototype.recData = function(data) 
{
     this.ping();
     var v = this.getStats();
     this.call("ack", 0, v.ping_rtt);
}

Client.prototype.echoData = function() 
{
     this.call("onEcho", 0, data);
};

Client.prototype.getBWInfo = function() 
{
     return this.getStats();
};

Client.prototype.onConnTimeout = function()
{
     clearInterval( this.connTimeout );
     this.connTimeout = null;
     application.disconnect(this);
}

application.onConnect = function(client, id)
{
     trace("connect: ");
     // Establish the connection
      application.acceptConnection(client);
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all the Client.prototype methods sit within their own function, ie:

```
application.onAppStart = function (info){

    ////////// start bandwidth check methods ////////////////
    for ( i = 0; i < 500; i++ ) {
    data += "S->C";
}

Client.prototype.recData = function(data) 
{
    this.ping();
    var v = this.getStats();
    this.call("ack", 0, v.ping_rtt);
}
...etc
    ////////// end bandwidth check methods ////////////////
}

application.onConnect = function(client_obj, id) {
    application.acceptConnection(client_obj);
}
```

Also does the app work with a local version of FMS?

Comment: Using the new EC2 public AMI of version 4.0.2 it just started working. I can't explain it, as I was using the exact same code before.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the same block of code. It's in the logs -- data is undefined.

Put:

var data = ''

Before everything else.